# Оптимизация работы с памятью

Tags: android

Пишу проект под android, в котором много математических вычислений и работы с матрицами. Как можно оптимизировать работу и хранение матриц?

Answer (score 1):

1. делить на 2 потока
2. если это игра, то лучше матрици, которые можно вычислить заранее - сделать уже готовыми константами
3. если там одна сложная математика - вынести локику на внешний сервер

Comment: тяжелый матрици ))  у чем твой вариант может выиграть в производительности я не понял, но как вариант оптимизации можно еще попробовать хранить матрици в векторах, например 3х3 в 9х1

Comment: особенности работы java,сам смотрел сначала в сторону коллекций, но они памяти много едят, танцы с бубном вокруг одномерного массива по этой же причине 
Всякий Java-объект имеет оверхед 8 байт  
Java-массив имеет дополнительный оверхед 4 байта (для хранения размера)  
Ссылка имеет размер 4 байта  
Размер всех объектов выровнен по 8 байт  
Многомерный массив — это массив ссылок на массивы.  
на пк и для небольших матриц  это как то неважно, но боюсь что на старых телефонах могут возникнуть проблемы

Comment: информация от сюда http://habrahabr.ru/post/142409/

Comment: многомерный массив - жто массив ссылок на массивы? в чем тут выигрыш?)) использовать одномерные массивы - это прием рефакторинга и оптимизации

Comment: вполне возможно, я чего-то не так понимаю, но ссылки тоже память занимают, я и стараюсь сейчас как-то оптимизировать узкие места, где могут быть проблемы

Comment: @gadfil, какраз там на хабре в 3м комментарии пишут про то что я говорю

Comment: спасибо спас от очередных грабель